# What is the correct HTML tag to use for entering a value to a search field?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am writing a macro to track shipment on a website by entering BL number in the first search field and click the Inquiry button. However I am getting an error with entering a value in the search field. The error line is "  SearchField.Value = "123456789"  ".

I appreciate if you can help guide me to correct this macro. Thank you in advance.

[Website for racking](https://www.hmm21.com/cms/business/ebiz/trackTrace/trackTrace/index.jsp)

```
Sub Tracking()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim SearchBy As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim SearchField As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim SearchButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

With IE
.Visible = True
.Navigate "https://www.hmm21.com/cms/business/ebiz/trackTrace/trackTrace/index.jsp"
End With

Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Dim objEvent As Object
Set objEvent = HTMLDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")

'Enter booking reference
Set SearchField = HTMLDoc.getElementById("blrow")
SearchField.Value = "123456789"
objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
SearchField.dispatchEvent objEvent

Set SearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("inquiryBtn")
SearchButton.Click

Set IE = Nothing
Set Result = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the search field by css selector:
`.type_input`

B/L Number: `#blfield1>input:nth-of-type(1)`

Comment: Can you please help to edit my above code with yours? I’m sorry as I am not proficient with css selector.